# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'c:\\Python27\test.txt'

Tags: python, file-io

What is wrong with the following:

```
test_file=open('c:\\Python27\test.txt','r')
```

Comment: Your question doubles the backslash in one place but not the second. Your code uses single backslashes.  Can you make the filename a raw string?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`\t` is a tab character. Use a raw string instead:

```
test_file=open(r'c:\Python27\test.txt','r')
```

or double the slashes:

```
test_file=open('c:\\Python27\\test.txt','r')
```

or use forward slashes instead:

```
test_file=open('c:/Python27/test.txt','r')
```

Comment: What If I want to access an external file? Like below? This too gives the same error message. 
fileResp = open('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', 'rb')

Comment: @KrishnaGupta: `open()` can only access files, not URLs.

Answer (score 3):

`\` is an escape character in Python. `\t` gets interpreted as a tab. If you need `\` character in a string, you have to use `\\`.

Your code should be:
`test_file=open('c:\\Python27\\test.txt','r')`

Answer (score 2):

always use 'r' to get a raw string when you want to avoid escape.

```
test_file=open(r'c:\Python27\test.txt','r')
```

Comment: Is there a way to prepend the raw modifier to a string?

Comment: yes, I cant believe noone gives an answer to this obvious question

Answer (score 1):

`\t` in a string marks an escape sequence for a tab character. For a literal `\`, use `\\`.