# Using CSV module to output some lines from a spreadsheet

Tags: python, csv

I am encountering an issue while using the csv module.

Here is my code

```
import csv

out = open('C:\Python27\Work\test.csv')
data = csv.reader(out)
data = [row for row in data]
out.close()

print data
```

The error I get is thus:

```
Line 3 in module,
out = open('C:\Python27\Work\test.csv')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Python27\\work\test.csv'
```

I'm confused because in the IOError it shows two backslashes (\) rather than one, which is very strange.

I've tried setting the mode to 'r', and 'rb' but nothing works.

When I use a different csv file, everything works just fine, and I get the output desired.

Comment: The error's not with the `csv` module. The error occurs when you open the file, before you pass it into `csv.reader`. As for the double backslashes, see the [documentation on string literals here](http://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598160/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-r-or-filename-c-python27-test-txt).  Seems to be that `\t` is interpreted as a tab character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\t` is interpreted as a tab character. There are two ways to fix this problem:

Change:

```
 'C:\Python27\Work\test.csv'
```

To a raw string

```
 r'C:\Python27\Work\test.csv'
```

Or escape the backslashes:

```
 'C:\\Python27\\Work\\test.csv'
```

Comment: Sure. Windows paths tend to be problematic because  the path separator happens to be a common escape character in programming.

Answer (score -1):

Two bugs:

1. In Windows you need scape the backslash: `out = open('C:\\Python27\\Work\\test.csv')`
2. By default the file is opened only read, when you assign the list to `data` variable, you are assigning the list to the csv-file object.  Change the the variable name like this:   `my_data = [row for row in data]`

Comment: @JoelCornett `data` isn't the name of the csv.reader? He's duplicated the name of the variable.

Comment: `data = csv.reader(out); data = [row for row in data]` works perfectly fine, although I would have prefered `data = list(csv.reader(out))`

Comment: While reassigning names is generally not a good programming practice, it won't cause an error in this script. If you don't believe me, try it yourself.

Comment: Also, your explanation of what is happening is incorrect. You aren't assigning anything to the CSV reader, you're merely changing what `data ` refers to.

Comment: @JoelCornett, you are all right.  I tried it myself and that don't generate an error.