# python saving my reviews to an text file

Tags: python

I'm struggling to save my multiple text files reviews to code it in python
this is my code for it:

```
print("Similarity Value: " + str(similarity))
print("Most Similar Watch: ")
print(mostSimilar)

with open("{}.txt".format(casebase[mostSimilar][0])) as review1:
    print(review1.read())

with open(filepath, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write('\n')
    myfile.write(str(unknowncase))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

what this shows now when I run it says:

> [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ' "L watch".txt'

but the files does exist in the specified folder too im not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You're attempting to *read* from a file that doesn't exist. This makes no sense. I assume this is the first `open()` call? The way your error is printed now, it looks like the filename you're trying to open is ` "L watch".txt` (just like that, with the space at the start and `"`) ... That doesn't sound quite correct to me ...

Comment: the file does exist as a text file but it cant find it and throws that error to me and yes it knows which text file to open which is the L text file but it says that file is not found when its there

Comment: Your mean to say you have a text file: '"L watch".txt'? look at the quotes in the error and check the filename

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOError: \[Errno 22\] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'c:\\Python27\test.txt'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598160/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-r-or-filename-c-python27-test-txt)

Comment: Are you **sure** that the file exists **exactly** like that, with a leading space and the quotation marks and the L?

Comment: Clearly your `open` call is not attempting to open what you think it is. Try setting the `format` value before the `open` call and printing it to see what it's actually attempting to open.

Comment: filename is that and i have checked the error its still giving me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

> [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ' "L watch".txt'

Notice that you are trying to read `"L watch".txt`, this is clearly wrong, I think you are want to read `L watch.txt`.
So your formating is substituting `{}` for `'"L watch"'` where should be substituting for `L watch` without quotes(`"`).

Usually read the errors carefully help a lot with this problems.
Happy hacking!!

**EDIT** - 2 posible solutions here:

```
with open("{}.txt".format(casebase[mostSimilar][0].strip('"')) as...
```

or

```
with open(filepath.replace('"', ""), "a") as myfile:
```

or both of them.

Comment: so what should i change in the code then? thankyou im a beginer