# Python Selenium webdriver throws IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename

Tags: python, selenium

**Software version details:**
Python: 2.7.12 
OS: Windows 10. 
Selenium: selenium-2.53.6
Firefox: 47.0

**Code snippet:**

```
import sys, urllib2

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The last line throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "queryWebsite.py", line 8,
>   in
>
> ```
> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 80, in __ init __
>
> ```
> self.binary, timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py",
> ```
>
> line 48, in __ init __
>
> ```
> self.profile.update_preferences()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py",
> ```
>
> line 97, in update_preferences
>
> ```
> self._write_user_prefs(self.default_preferences)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py",
> ```
>
> line 221, in _write_user_prefs
>       with open(self.userPrefs, "w") as f:
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:
>   'c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\temp\tmpgwa_ot\user.js'

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling your webdriver?  I wonder if it got messed up somehow.

Comment: Yes. Same error persists. I did the following.

pip uninstall selenium && 
pip install -U selenium --no-cache-dir (to download fresh)

Comment: I don't happen to have Python or a selenium driver for Python installed, but the problem being reported is that the call to open(self.userPrefs, "w") doesn't like the form of the string returned by self.userPrefs.  those single \'s shouldn't be used, or the string should be a raw string (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598160/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-r-or-filename-c-python27-test-txt).  Now, why this is happening in selenium code is strange.  You might want to look at firefox_profile.py to see how it's returning that self.userPrefs