# How to Enclose comma separated dictionaries in a list [ ] using python2.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of python dictionaries separated with commas in my file, i have to enclose these comma separated dictionaries in a python list to read my file as a json.

For Eg: myfile

```
{
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
},
{
    "title": "Sample Widget",
    "name": "main_window1",
    "width": 300,
    "height": 200
}
```

I have to make this as

```
[
{
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
},
{
    "title": "Sample Widget",
    "name": "main_window1",
    "width": 300,
    "height": 200
}
]
```

Any suggestions, how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
import json
d = json.loads('[{}]'.format(open('myfile').read()))
```

Comment: Not working, Getting below error

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:

Comment: Are you sure you can open that myfile? And what you have in that `open()` exactly -- [IOError 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598160/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-r-or-filename-c-python27-test-txt) may mean you have backslashes problem?