# I'm unable to create a file in python (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unable to create a file in python (full path).

Code:

```py
with open('C:/Users/Kobe/backtra/data/BTC-USDT_25-05-20-19:02:19.json', "w+"):
    pass
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\createFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open("C:/Users/Kobe/backtra/data/BTC-USDT_25-05-20-19:02:19.json", "w+"):
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Kobe/backtra/data/BTC-USDT_25-05-20-19:02:19.json'
```

Comment: Try using `"` and if that doesnt help then try using `//` instead of `/`

Comment: Check that you have the right permissions on the path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOError: \[Errno 22\] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'c:\\Python27\test.txt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598160/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-r-or-filename-c-python27-test-txt)

Comment: Try adding ```r``` prefix to the path.

Comment: @meyer1994/@John Single forward slash is just fine in windows. @Kobe Please include the entire stack trace

Comment: Check whether the path exists or not. If it exists add prefix 'r' to path i.e. ```'C:/Users/Kobe/backtra/data/BTC-USDT_25-05-20-19:02:19.json'```

Comment: @SUDHEERTALLURI No, I want to create this file.

Comment: @John There is no difference between `'` and `"`. `/` is not a special symbol, there is no need to repeat it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice  w+ parameter. If prefix r doesn't work. check for the permissioins. Try running your console as administrator or change the permissions in the system.

Comment: What if you try:
`"\"C:/Users/Kobe/backtra/data/BTC-USDT_25-05-20-19:02:19.json\""` because windows likes having `"` when given a path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows file names cannot contain ':'.

If you remove the ':' it should work:

```
with open('C:/Users/Kobe/backtra/data/BTC-USDT_25-05-20-190219.json', "w+"):
    pass
```